# How to restore GRUB after windows XP installation?

Tags: arch-linux, grub, windows, dual-boot, mbr

After I've installed windows xp for dual booting, I need to restore grub of my archlinux installation. I did it a lot of times with windows 7, but this time heavens decided to torture me.
I have opensuse liveKDE usb drive inserted into my laptop. My currect drive is /dev/sda with /dev/sda1 -> archlinux /; /dev/sda2 -> /home; /dev/sda3 -> windows xp.

In liveKDE konsole I mount my /dev/sda1 to /mnt/arch, chroot /mnt/arch /bin/bash and run grub.
Trying root (hdX,Y) I get "selected disk does not exist". So I try grub-install /dev/sda, which gives me "Not found or not a block device". I have tried other variants like grub-install.unsupported /dev/sda, which gave me "/dev/loop0 does not have any corresponding BIOS drive", arrrr!

I'm out of options here, does anybody have an idea of some competent liveCD to start with. I tried Super Grub Disk, didn't work cause it froze all the time. Tried Rescatux but it does not have grub available in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I did it. 
from liveCD (Archbang in my case) under root:

1. mkdir /mnt/root
2. mount -t ext4 /dev/sdaX /mnt/root
3. mount -t proc none /mnt/root/proc
4. mount -o bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
5. chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
6. grub
7. find /boot/grub/stage1
8. root (hdX,Y)
9. setup (hdX)
10. quit
11. reboot

This should work. Archlinux wiki has an article which explains the process in more [detail](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Run_grub-install_from_a_live_CD).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this once,And it worked for me..I installed windows xp dual boot with Ubuntu.
Same problem occured to me, i followed the steps below hope it can work with you...
Using Ubuntu live dvd..

The graphical way

1: Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.

2: Install and run Boot-Repair

3: Click "Recommended Repair".

4: Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.